# form_set_error() doesn't work in exposed_validate()

Tags: 7, views, forms

I have made a custom module which implements a new field for Field API and a filter for Views. Everything works like a charm except value validation for exposed filters. I will describe a problem step by step:

1. Made a new view and added two my custom filters on it.
2. Made them exposed (both value and operator).
3. Named operators as 'date_op' and 'period_op', and filters as 'date' and 'period' (they MUST be named differently for obvious reasons).
4. Made both filters 'required'.

In the  value_form() function form element is defined as:

```
$form['value'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Value'),
      '#size' => 25,
      '#default_value' => $this->value,
    );
```

In the exposed_validate() function there is a code which check values for validity and call form_set_error () function in the case of error. But in fact form_set_error() neither show error message nor draw red border around a wrong form element! Form is just simply redisplayed without any visible error. :-(

This is a code excerpts of my exposed_validate() function:

```
...
$identifier = $this->options['expose']['identifier'];
...
if (!empty($this->options['expose']['required'])) {
  dpm($identifier, 'Required!'); // So I can see that this part of function is really executed.
  form_set_error($identifier, t('This field is required and must be set.')); // Neither error message nor red border here :-(
  form_set_error('period', t('Period error! ')); // As above, neither error message nor red border
  form_set_error('period_op', t('Period_op error! ')); // Both error message and red border around operator element are visible
  form_set_error('value', t('Value error!')); // Error message only, but no red border (because there is no such element on a form)
```

As you can see, form_set_error() function trying to find a form element named 'value' (as described in value_form() function) but there is no such element on form, there are only 'date' and 'period' ones. And it is strange enough that form_set_error() call for operators works as expected.

So, the question is: how to make a form_set_error() to highlight a right element on a form in the case of error?

Comment: It seems that problen not in my module but in the Views or Form API itself: http://drupal.org/node/1828106